# Using bzgrep recursively

Tags: grep, bzip2

I wanted to use `bzgrep` to find to text in bzip2 files.

I expected `bzgrep` to work as `grep`, but on bz2 files.

So I tried `bzgrep -r "mypattern" .` to find text in my bz2 files.

Instead of the expected result I get the same result as `grep` : It found the text only in `.txt` files.

Any idea how to use `bzgrep` recursively ?

I am using `grep (GNU grep) 2.18`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me as expected:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir sub
echo pattern > {.,sub}/f{1,2}
echo nomatch > {.,sub}/f3
bzip2 {.,sub}/f2

/tmp $ grep -r pattern .
./f1:pattern
./sub/f1:pattern

/tmp $ bzgrep -r pattern .
./f1:pattern
./f2.bz2:pattern
./sub/f1:pattern
./sub/f2.bz2:pattern
```

Could you verify and post your version of grep?

```
$ grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 2.18

Comment: On a machine with GNU grep 2.6.3, it's doesn't even work anymore. Bzgrep returns "bzip2: Input file . is a directory" when running with -r option.

Comment: Looks like you have to go with a scripted solution then. Something like `find . -type f -name \*.bz2 -exec bzgrep pattern {} /dev/null` might work, but you will have to handle non-bz2 files separately (using a second grep invocation for example).